# Task Scheduled Powershell Script Not Shutting Down machine

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v, task-scheduler, schtasks

I have a task running on a Hyper-V server setup as such:

```
schtasks /CREATE /TN AutoShutdown /RU "SYSTEM" /TR "Powershell \"C:\AutoShutdown.ps1\"" /SC ONSTART
```

It runs properly (as far as I can tell) however the script has a line to shutdown the computer and it never does.

```
start-sleep 120
while (1) {$vm = get-vm; if ($vm.state -ne "Running") {stop-computer} else {"Running..."; start-sleep 10}}
```

If I run the task in user space:

```
schtasks /CREATE /TN AutoShutdown /TR "Powershell \"C:\AutoShutdown.ps1\"" /SC ONLOGIN
```

It runs perfectly.

Comment: If someone is logged in, stop-computer will not execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stop-computer needs the -force flag to work I guess when running as a process.  Switching to `stop-computer -force` fixed the problem.